# AutoMapper with custom attribute[AutoMapper]: how to add a condition on a property

Tags: c#, attributes, automapper

I'm using autoMapper and using attributes to map between entity and model.
I want to add a condition when creating the map.
I tried ForMember but it doesn't work since my condition is on a specific property and my sourceType and destinationType are somehow dynamic.
Is there a way to keep mapping with using attribute and at the same time add a condition on a property if it exists ?

Comment: From a personal experience I would say : "run away from automapper", it use reflection (slowing stuff down) and this can be confusing.

Comment: @pix That was true maybe five years ago :)

Comment: it would help if you post your models (from - to) and describe the condition you are trying to implement

Comment: I'm using custom attributes so for every DTO I give the attribute [AutoMapper(typeof(entity))]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with attributes. You'll have to switch to the fluent API.